# Errors when starting Qgis 3

Tags: qgis

After launching Qgis 3.2 Desktop I receive the following error messages:

> > Impossibile caricare PyQt. Il supporto Python verrà disabilitato.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ImportError:
>   DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata.
>
> Versione Python:
>   3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> Versione di QGIS:
>   3.2.0-Bonn 'Bonn', bc43194061
>
> Percorso Python: ['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python',
>   'C:/Users/Mascia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python',
>   'C:/Users/Mascia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins',
>   'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
>   'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python36.zip',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\DLLs',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib', 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin',
>   'C:\Users\Mascia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages']
>
> > Blockquote

and this

> Si è verificato un errore durante l'esecuzione delle istruzioni
>   seguenti: qgis.utils.uninstallErrorHook()
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  NameError:
>   name 'qgis' is not defined
>
> Versione Python:
>   3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> Versione di QGIS:
>   3.2.0-Bonn 'Bonn', bc43194061
>
> Percorso Python: ['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python',
>   'C:/Users/Mascia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python',
>   'C:/Users/Mascia/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins',
>   'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
>   'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python36.zip',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\DLLs',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib', 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin',
>   'C:\Users\Mascia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36',
>   'C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages']

Comment: the second one looks like [this very recent QGIS issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19374). The first one looks like it's not finding pyqt (or it's finding an old version from 2.18). Try running QGIS without plugins (from osgeo4w shell, run qgis --no-plugins) to see if it's one of your plugins causing the problem.